# Stop Timer inside Thread Android

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I have a Timer running in a Thread. This is the code:

```
timer = new Timer();
start_timer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            Log.e("asd", String.valueOf(tmp_chiamata_id)); 

            //do somethings

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), start_timer.getState().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        });
      }
    }, 0, 1000);
  }
});
start_timer.start();
```

To stop the timer i write this:

```
if(timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        start_timer.interrupt();
}
```

The problem is that the logcat stop to display asd but the toast continuing show the message Interrupted. I also tried to stop the thread with start_timer.stop() but it doesn't work anyway. How can I do?
Thanks, Mattia

Comment: you know timer starts its own thread right? also anything your going to do that effects the ui should be done through a handler

Comment: I solved. Timer and thread stop correctly, there was another error not depending on these two objects

Answer (score 0):

It is more stable and easier to use a handler and send delayed messages

https://web.archive.org/web/20200810154212/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calling purge() method from timer object would help. As document says,

"Removes all canceled tasks from the task queue. If there are no other references on the tasks, then after this call they are free to be garbage collected."